# Importing Modules within Scripts in Python Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having two issues with attempting to define my own class. First, the most basic issue is that if I write a python script and try to import it into a second script, the import fails (the scripts are in the same directory). For example, I wrote a script called first.py:

```
def foo(): print("foo")
```

If I try to import this into a second script, I get 'no module found'

```
import first

first.foo()

ImportError: No module named first
```

Second, I wrote a script that defines a class for non-linear regression. The script imports the modules within the class. However, I'm also required to import the modules OUTSIDE of the class as well. The script won't work if the modules aren't imported both inside and outside of the class definition:

```
class NLS:
    ''' This provides a wrapper for scipy.optimize.leastsq to get the relevant output for nonlinear least squares.
    Although scipy provides curve_fit for that reason, curve_fit only returns parameter estimates and covariances.
    This wrapper returns numerous statistics and diagnostics'''
    # IMPORT THE MODULES THE FIRST TIME - WILL NOT RUN WITHOUT THESE
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.optimize import leastsq 
    import scipy.stats as spst


    def __init__(self, func, p0, xdata, ydata):

         # Check the data
        if len(xdata) != len(ydata):
            msg = 'The number of observations does not match the number of rows for the predictors'
            raise ValueError(msg)

        # Check parameter estimates
        if type(p0) != dict:
            msg = "Initial parameter estimates (p0) must be a dictionry of form p0={'a':1, 'b':2, etc}"
            raise ValueError(msg)

        self.func = func
        self.inits = p0.values()
        self.xdata = xdata
        self.ydata = ydata
        self.nobs = len( ydata )
        self.nparm= len( self.inits )

        self.parmNames = p0.keys()

        for i in range( len(self.parmNames) ):
            if len(self.parmNames[i]) > 5:
                self.parmNames[i] = self.parmNames[i][0:4]

        # Run the model
        self.mod1 = leastsq(self.func, self.inits, args = (self.xdata, self.ydata), full_output=1)

        # Get the parameters
        self.parmEsts = np.round( self.mod1[0], 4 )

        # Get the Error variance and standard deviation
        self.RSS = np.sum( self.mod1[2]['fvec']**2 )
        self.df = self.nobs - self.nparm
        self.MSE = self.RSS / self.df
        self.RMSE = np.sqrt( self.MSE )

        # Get the covariance matrix
        self.cov = self.MSE * self.mod1[1]

        # Get parameter standard errors
        self.parmSE = np.diag( np.sqrt( self.cov ) )

        # Calculate the t-values
        self.tvals = self.parmEsts/self.parmSE

        # Get p-values
        self.pvals = (1 - spst.t.cdf( np.abs(self.tvals), self.df))*2

        # Get biased variance (MLE) and calculate log-likehood
        self.s2b = self.RSS / self.nobs
        self.logLik = -self.nobs/2 * np.log(2*np.pi) - self.nobs/2 * np.log(self.s2b) - 1/(2*self.s2b) * self.RSS

        del(self.mod1)
        del(self.s2b)
        del(self.inits)        

    # Get AIC. Add 1 to the df to account for estimation of standard error
    def AIC(self, k=2):
        return -2*self.logLik + k*(self.nparm + 1)

    del(np)
    del(leastsq)

    # Print the summary
    def summary(self):
        print
        print 'Non-linear least squares'
        print 'Model: ' + self.func.func_name
        print 'Parameters:'
        print "               Estimate      Std. Error      t-value      P(>|t|)"
        for i in range( len(self.parmNames) ):
            print "%   -5s          % 5.4f       % 5.4f         % 5.4f      % 5.4f" % tuple( [self.parmNames[i], self.parmEsts[i], self.parmSE[i], self.tvals[i], self.pvals[i]] )                
        print
        print 'Residual Standard Error: % 5.4f' % self.RMSE
        print 'Df: %i' % self.df


## EXAMPLE USAGE
import pandas as pd
# IMPORT THE MODULES A SECOND TIME. WILL NOT RUN WITHOUT THESE
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq 
import scipy.stats as spst

# Import data into dataframe
respData = pd.read_csv('/Users/Nate/Documents/FIU/Research/MTE_Urchins/Data/respiration.csv')

# Standardize to 24 h
respData['respDaily'] = respData['C_Resp_Mass'] * 24

# Create the Arrhenius temperature
respData['Ar'] = -1 / (8.617 * 10**-5 * (respData['Temp']+273))

# Define the likelihood null model
def nullMod(params, mass, yObs):
    a = params[0]
    c = params[1]    
    yHat = a*mass**c
    err = yObs - yHat
    return(err)


p0 = {'a':1, 'b':1}

tMod = NLS(nullMod, p0, respData['UrchinMass'], respData['respDaily'] )

tMod.summary()

tMod.AIC()

tMod.logLik
```

These problems are related because I try to import this class into another script and I can't (as in the first problem). Can anyone tell me what's going on?

**Update**

I just started being able to import scripts. Whatever that funky clean on start path was appears to have finally been deleted somehow. No idea what that was. However, I still don't understand why, if I import the necessary modules in my class definition, I MUST import them in my other scripts as well. It seems to me that if my class imports the modules, I shouldn't need to import them globally as well. Is this correct?

Comment: is `first.py` in the same folder with your current script or it's path  in `sys.path` list?

Comment: What if you *only* import the `numpy` and `scipy` at the top of your script, before the class definition. Also, why do you have the statements `del(np)' and `del(leastsq)`; that seems really odd.

Comment: As for the first part of your question: this works fine for me. Those lines you're showing are really the only lines of code in your test scripts?

Comment: Can you import `first` from the Python command line (still in the same directory)?

Comment: yes those lines in the test scripts really are the only lines. Also, first.py is in the same folder with the current script. I can't import first from the command line, but I don't know how to set the directory to my desktop. Moving the import commands to the top of the script still results in an error

Comment: Ok, that does seem odd. No need to set/change a directory: if there's a Python module (script) there and you are in that directory, it should import. What's your system though? And if relevant, what Python do you have installed (eg standard, activestate, perhaps jython etc)?

Comment: Do remove those `del(np)` and `del(leastsq)` statements though; I don't really see the use. (Nor for the other `del` statements; I don't think that's where any memory savings will be achieved, if that is an issue.)

Comment: I'm using standard python 2.7 on Mac OS X. I tried removing the del() statements after your first comments and nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I think the first comment from zhangxaochen is the best starting place for problem number number 1.  sys.path should contain all the paths that python is searching for when you try to import a module.  These are the steps I'd go through to solve this one:

Make sure os.getcwd() returns the same directory as os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

Next I'd make sure that that path is in sys.path list.

If both those check out....

Comment: OK I tried the first diagnosis of making sure os.getswd() is the same directory as os.path.dirname(). It's not. os.getcwd() returns: /Users/Nate/Desktop while os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) returns: /private/var/folders/zl/yxc7hlld61b6y2n5ghnn_q4h0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup. What in the world is that second folder? The first one is the directory of (both) scripts. When I try sys.path, the second weird file path is in the list, but my Desktop is not.

Comment: @Nate Ok, that's weird. Could you check on your terminal cmdline the following commands: `which python` and then `ls -l \`which python\``? It would feel like the python you're running got a symlink to some really weird file. Btw, `sys.path` may contain an empty string `''` as first element, which indicates your current directory, i.e., Desktop in your case. So if Desktop isn't listed, it may still be there.

Comment: Hmm weird indeed!  Don't know why you get that as your sys.argv[0].  Are you running the script from an ide or on the command line?  When you print sys.path is /Users/Nate/Desktop in the list of directories?  If its not then add it and then try the import.

Comment: I was running it from a command line. I've since gotten it to work but, in all honesty, I don't know how. I just opened and closed python enough that it appears to have been fixed.